# PySide QML project on android

Tags: android, python, qt, qml, pyside

I have made an application over pyside and qml for pc and I am interested to know how I can run this on android tablet.
P.S.: My Program uses socket, threading and mongodb too.

Answer (score 2):

I think its too big an answer and redundant as such. Will just point directly to the link :

http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_for_Android_guide

Also google for 'Necessitas' for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look :

https://github.com/raaron/pydroid

PyDroid is easier than pySide guide. But you should install it on ubuntu, or ubuntu with virtualBox. But first you should install Necessitas, Ant before setup PyDroid. If it is able to run Necessitas projec app on your device, then you can install PyDroid. Because PyDroid depends on Necessitas SDK. After installation of PyDroid, you open file manager as root, "show hidden files", go to /root/.pydroid location and open deploy.config, edit "adb-path"(type terminal "whereis adb" to find location) and necessitas location. after that it is easy to deploy android app with PyDroid.